# Ids de los elementos HTML en los iframes

Tags: html, iframe

Mi caso es el siguiente, tengo en una página 3 iframes, en cada iframe hay lo mismo, que es una tabla con datos y 2 botones. Tengo entendido que en html está mal o feo o lo que sea poner por ejemplo 3 input text con el mismo id. Ahora mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿En los 2 iframes se puede repetir el mismo id? Me explico:

Tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dos iframes, cada uno con los mismos elementos pero distintos datos. Hay 2 input text, ambos input text tienen el mismo id para poder obtener el valor de ese campo al darle al botón editar, ¿esto estaría mal "diseñado"/"programado"? ¿Supondría algún problema para la web? Funcionar me funciona pero no se.

Quiero decir, si cada iframe son elementos independientes del otro iframe o puede haber confusión al poner el mismo id en ambos iframes.

No se si he explicado bien lo que pregunto. Lo siento.

Saludos.

Comment: En ningun html deberias repetir `ID`'s porque es un valor único. Usa otros atributos/propiedades  como `name`.

Comment: Es buena pregunta, porque si lo haces con iframes se puede dar el caso de integrar un html con ids iguales... Pero en tu caso, lo que haria es sustituir los iframes por divs. SI realmente necesitas esos iframes, cambia los ids y utiliza atributos en los campos para indicar y obtener el id correspondiente.

Comment: No hay ningún problema en ello ya que son documentos DOM independientes. Desde el documento/marco padre no podrás acceder a los IDs de los documentos/marcos hijos a través de `document.getElementById()`, deberás usar el `getElementById()` de cada hijo para encontrarlos. Por cierto, ¿para qué necesitas trabajar con `iframe`s? ¿no puedes hacerlo sin depender de ellos?